# Using PCA to find most 'similar' points to a given observation (mixed data)

Tags: clustering, pca, data-mining, mixed-type-data

I am trying to find the most 'similar' points to each other in a dataset of mixed data. I understand that if these were all numeric variables on the same scale, one could simply use Euclidean Distance or some other clustering type dissimilarity measure. Since my data is mixed and on different scales, I'm wondering if PCA would be better here? I don't need concrete measures of distance like a dissimilarity matrix would provide but rather I want to be able to look at two points and say, these are relatively similar/dissimilar.

Would PCA and plotting the first two PCs accomplish this?

Comment: PCA essentially *assumes* Euclidean distance. So you will not get around that by doing PCA.

Comment: @amoeba does what I said make sense though?

Comment: No, it won't make sense. You should decide what is "similar" given your mixed type data. Then compute the distance matrix and/or or do cluster analysis or nearest neighbour search.

Comment: @ttnphns how do I decide what is similar given the mixed data type? What if it is all numeric but on different scales?

Comment: Gower similarity?